# $facebook->getSignedRequest(); return the correct value in iframe while return null on my server side

Tags: api, facebook-like

i am building a fan gate for my site to give out some coupon.
here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));

print_r($_REQUEST);

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($facebook->getSignedRequest());
echo "</pre>";

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];

print_r($facebook);

?>
```

I find that the return value of $facebook->getSignedRequest(); is different when i am visiting my apps via apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/ and when i am visiting www.coupon.mysite.com/facebook/index.php

via apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/:
Facebook Object ( [appId:protected] => 15255288xxxxxxxx [appSecret:protected] => XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX[user:protected] => [signedRequest:protected] => Array ( [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256 [issued_at] => xxxxxxxxxxxxx[user] => Array ( [country] => hk [locale] => en_US [age] => Array ( [min] => 21 ) ) ) [state:protected] => [accessToken:protected] => [fileUploadSupport:protected] => )

via www.coupon.mysite.com/facebook/index.php:
Facebook Object ( [appId:protected] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[appSecret:protected] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx[user:protected] => [signedRequest:protected] => [state:protected] => [accessToken:protected] => [fileUploadSupport:protected] => )

so the fan gate wont work because $facebook->getSignedRequest(); always return null in my server side. I have do the searching for this problem for some days already and still dont understand what is the problem.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Obviously it is different. It is facebook that posts the 'signed_request' data to your iframe, so when you're not viewing the page through the iframe, how could facebook post the data to your page?

Comment: um.... ic your point, but how could i receive the post from my side?  well this is my question indeed.... thanks for comment

Comment: you cannot, you can only get the signed request data if the page is viewed through Facebook; I mean, what would you expect that data to be if a user navigates directly to your server (such user may have no connected to Facebook whatsoever). Anyways, one solution would be to redirect users arrivign directly at your server to the Facebook page, e.g. if `$_POST['signed_request']` is not set

Comment: um... but i often see some like-hidden content in some site or forum, how do I achieve that?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "like-hidden content"

Comment: like this : http://jeradhill.com/click-like-to-view-this-content

Answer (score 1):

^ ... continue from the comments:

First of all, if you do this, your users will hate you; secondly, that plugin is bit of a scam - all it does is uses cookies to store if user has liked a page - but if you delete your cookies, you will be locked out of the content because you won't be able to like the page again. Furthermore, it won't work without Javascript.

All the plugin does is it hooks into the "like" action when user clicks on the like button via

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, response){});
```

[facebook graph api determine if user likes url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322033/facebook-graph-api-determine-if-user-likes-url)

Comment: i don't do this then my boss hate me more than the user.... but anyway,  thank you very much