# Facebook Like Button - Is It Checked?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I'm having trouble finding good documentation about how to use javascript in order to find out if a like button is clicked or not.  I can't use an on-click event because the button might already be checked when a user comes onto my page but that seems to be all I can find regarding tracking likes externally (not counting other methods that are no longer supported).  Anyone have any experience with such issues?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure there's something in the API. If there isn't, see if the button has a specific `class` when it is checked.

Comment: I tried looking but facebook's API is just downright difficult to find solid answers and/or examples (not to mention there seems to be a lot of deprecated documentation still up).  I'll take a look to see if there's any specific class applied, but at first glance it doesn't appear to have one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Like button. If it's for a Facebook object that has an ID, you can query the **like** table (but you'll need *user_likes* permission)

If it's for a URL, it's not really possible: [facebook graph api determine if user likes url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322033/facebook-graph-api-determine-if-user-likes-url) [stackoverflow]

It it's for a [built-in like](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/) you could use a cookie to remember the click, or save the click in your own database.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on Gil's answer. For built-in likes you can use a batch request consisting of two request:
1) Try to like the object in question
2) If there was no error, delete the like connection

Example batch:

```
[{"method":"POST", "relative_url":"me/og.likes", "body":"object=<SOME_URL>", "name":"like-attempt", "omit_response_on_success": false},
{"method":"DELETE", "relative_url":"{result=like-attempt:$.id}"}]
```

If an object was already liked, batch response would be:

```
[
    {
        "code": 400,
        "headers": [
            ...
            {
                "name": "WWW-Authenticate",
                "value": "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"invalid_request\" \"(#3501) User is already associated to the object object on a unique action type Like. Original Action ID: 143539809123515\""
            }
        ],
        "body": "{\n \"error\": {\n \"message\": \"(#3501) User is already associated to the object object on a unique action type Like. Original Action ID: 143539809123515\",\n \"type\": \"OAuthException\",\n \"code\": 3501\n }\n}"
    },
    null
]
```

So to check if object was liked, JSON.parse the first response body and look for an error with error code `3501`. Keep in mind that the actual error code is not documented anywhere so it could change, although I don't think it is likely.